# Getting controller('form') inside ng-repeat does not work

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that generates an input dinamically, my code looks more or less like this:

```
    compile: function (element, attrs) {
        var control = element.find('input');
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var form = control.controller('form');
            scope.field = form[control.attr('name')];
        }
    }
```

Well it works very nice, scope.field gets the $dirty, $valid etc. properties so I can use them inside my template, it's very good.

But if the HTML is inside a ng-repeat control.controller('form') throws undefined

Example:

```
        <fieldset ng-repeat="reference in application">
            <field model="reference.name"
                   type="text"
                   label="Name">
            </field>
```

Without the fieldset ng-repeat it works, but with it, it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: You don't add a `name` attribute to you `<fields>`

Comment: I add it to the input dinamically in the same directive.